# Trigger cross-project-pipelines for tags and manual jobs

Tags: gitlab, microservices, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

Gitlab's cross-project-pipeline allows me to [specify a branch](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/24/cross-project-pipeline/) to run a pipeline for. I didn't find any such option to do the same with a tag?

Since my cross-project-pipeline is also being run deliberately, is it also possible to run all manual jobs in a downstream pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible with [Triggering pipelines through the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/).

You just need to add the following to your CI script:

```
- curl --request POST --form "token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" --form ref=master https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/trigger/pipeline
```

and update the `ref` to be the tag you require, and `<project-id>` with the project you are triggering.

---

In terms of the cross-project pipeline being run deliberately and having manual jobs you want to run when being triggered, you'd probably need to re-write the downstream CI file to allow for that, eg:

Upstream CI file:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Do some building..."
    # Trigger downstream project (tag v1.0.0), with a random variable
    - curl --request POST --form "token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" \
        --form "variables[RANDOM_VARIABLE]=FOO" \
        --form ref=v1.0.0 https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/trigger/pipeline
```

Downstream CI file:

```
.test:template:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Running some test"

test:manual:
  extends:
    - .test:template
  when: manual
  except:
    - triggers

test:triggered:
  extends:
    - .test:template
  only:
    - triggers
```

So when a triggered job is run, the `test:triggered` should be the only `test` job you see in the pipeline.

See [only/except](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic) documents for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to run the downstream pipeline using trigger job, you can specify the branch or **tag** using `trigger:branch` ([docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html?tab=Multi-project%20pipeline#specify-a-branch-for-multi-project-pipelines)).

Job in upstream pipeline:

```
job1:
  trigger:
    project: my-downstream-project
    branch: tag-in-downstream-project
```

Job in downstream pipeline

```
job2:
  only:
    - pipelines  # Optional
  # Rest of the job
```

In the downstream pipeline you can specify that the job should be included only when the pipeline is triggered by the upstream (in this example the job1).

In addition , calling the downstream pipeline in job1 allows you to wait for the completion of job2 when you use `trigger:strategy: depend`